# Pandas remove text after a set of keywords in the column

Tags: python, python-3.x, regex, pandas, dataframe

I have a pandas data frame which looks like as shown below

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'person_id': [11,11,11,11,11,11],
                   'details':['DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO PRN Test','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject  hypo gdksajgfkjsagf > 4 test value here','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube START 10:00 AM','DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO QTY removed']})
```

I would like to remove part of the text from the `details` column based on below logic

a) If the text value contains keywords such as `PRN`, `Hypo`, `START` or `QTY removed`, then remove everything that comes after those keywords. **The keywords could be lower or upper case as well**

I was trying something like below

```
df['text'].str.rsplit(r'prn|hypo|start|qty removed', 1).str.get(0) # this doesn't work
```

I expect my output to be like as shown below. Please note that my datatset has 4-5 million records, so any efficient and elegant approach would really be helpful

[image]

Comment: `df['text'].str.replace(r'(?i)(prn|hypo|start|qty removed).*', '')`?

Comment: what does `?i` do?

Comment: can you write as an answer please? I can accept it

Comment: It is an inline modifier that makes searching case insensitive.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Series.str.replace` rather than `rsplit`:

```
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace(r'(?i)\s*\b(prn|hypo|start|qty removed).*', '')
# >>> df['details'].str.replace(r'(?i)\s*\b(prn|hypo|start|qty removed).*', '')
# 0    DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject
# 1        DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO
# 2      DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube
# 3    DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Inject
# 4      DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - Tube
# 5        DOSE: 667 mg - TDS with food - PO
# Name: details, dtype: object
```

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/eWRQzi/1). Details:

- `(?i)` - an inline modifier making regex search case insensitive
- `\s*` - zero or more whitespace chars
- `\b` - a whole word marker, word boundary
- `(prn|hypo|start|qty removed)` - a group of alternative strings (capturing, you may turn it into a non-capturing by replacing `(` with `(?:`)
- `.*` - the rest of the line (any zero or more chars other than line break chars, as many as possible).

Answer (score 0):

We could do [`Series.str.replace`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.replace.html) with `case = False` in order
not to distinguish between upper and lower case

```
df['details'] = df['details'].str.replace('prn|hypo|start|qty removed', '', 
                                          regex=True, case=False)
```